# Robust Serial Protocol with Auto Retransmit questions

Tags: c, embedded, uart, usart

long time reader, first time poster.

I have a serial link between a sensor and a base station via bluetooth. The bluetooth link is incredibly unreliable and drops packets like you wouldnt believe. I'm using this as a positive and going to design a robust serial protocol that can survive a shit link.

Just wanna bounce some ideas off of people as i'm the only embedded developer in the office.

Plan is to use byte stuffing to create packets with start (STX) and end (ETX) bytes, index number and CRC. Am planning on using an escape character (DLE) when the STX and ETX and DLE characters come up. That part is all pretty clear and here is said code that should do that

```
static void SendCommand(struct usart_module * const usart_module, uint16_t cmd,
        uint8_t *data, uint8_t len)
{
    //[STX] ( { [IDX] [CMD_H] [CMD_L] [LEN] ...[DATA]... } [CRC] ) [ETX] // Data in {} brackets is XORed together for the CRC. // Data in () is the packet length
    static uint8_t idx;
    uint8_t packet[256];
    uint8_t crc, packetLength, i;

    if (len > 250)
        return;

    packetLength = len + 5;

    packet[0] = idx++;
    packet[1] = (cmd >> 8);
    packet[2] = (cmd & 0x00FF);
    packet[3] = packetLength;

    crc = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        crc ^= packet[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        packet[4 + i] = data[i];
        crc ^= data[i];
    }

    packet[4 + len] = crc;

    // Send Packet
    uart_putc(usart_module, STX);
    for (i = 0; i < packetLength; i++)
    {
        if ((packet[i] == STX) || (packet[i] == ETX) || (packet[i] == DLE))
        {
            uart_putc(usart_module, DLE);
        }
        uart_putc(usart_module, packet[i]);
    }
    uart_putc(usart_module, ETX);
}
```

So that will send a packet, but now i need to add some code to keep track of the packets and retransmit the failed ones automatically and thats where i need some help with some ideas.

Couple options i had;
-Easiest, assign a giant array of 256 packets, each with enough room to store a packet and after transmitting the packet, put it in the buffer and if i dont receive an ACK after x amount of time, transmit it again. Then if i do receive an ACK, delete that record from the array so that entry is blank so i know it got received just fine.

Issue with that is that if i use the worst case packet size of 256 bytes, and 256 instances of them, thats 64K of RAM and i dont have that (and even if i did, thats a terrible idea)

-Next idea, create a linked list of all the packets and dynamically assign memory using the malloc commands etc. and remove the ones that got acknowledged, and keep the ones that havent so i know which to retransmit after x time.

Issues i have with that is the entire malloc idea. Truthfully, i've never used it and i dont like the idea of using it in an embedded environment with limited memory. Maybe thats just me being silly, but i feel like thats opening the door to a bucket load of other problems i dont need.

-Potential solution, create a linked list for all packets like mentioned above, but create them in a fifo, and move all the records around to keep them in the fifo.

e.g. 
send packet 1, put packet in in the fifo
send packet 2, put packet in in the fifo
receive NACK for packet 1, do nothing
send packet 3, put packet in in the fifo
receive ACK for packet 2, memset packet 2 to 0x00 in fifo
receive ACK for packet 3, memset packet 2 to 0x00 in fifo
send packet 4, put packet in in the fifo
send packet 5, put packet in in the fifo
no more room in FIFO, go through and shuffle everything to the front because where packet 2 and 3 were is empty now.

Could keep them shuffled in real time, but then we need to shuffle a whole fifo after every packet received and that seems like a lot of unnecessary work?

What i'm looking for is for one of you to say "Jeez Ned, thats not bad, but if you just do xyz, then that saves you heaps of work or RAM or complexity" or something.

Just want a couple people to bounce ideas off of really as thats how you generally get the best solution. I like my solution, but i feel like i'm missing something, or am over complicating it maybe? not sure... i just dont feel 100% happy with this idea i dont think, but just cant think of a better way.

Comment: Do you really need to juggle multiple packets at once?  Why not just retry one packet until you get an ACK before transmitting the next?

Comment: I struggled with that myself as well, but if i can do multiple packets at once, then i dont have to wait a 'long' time between packets to make sure they got there, and instead load up a bunch of data to be sent out quickly.

Comment: I have some scenarios where i'm sending 100 packets in short succession, so being able to have the receiver process them while the transmitter keeps sending would be great. It will greatly speed up the data transfer

Comment: google xmodem, ymodem, zmodem.  keep transmitting numbered packets, collect acks or nacks, retry the ones that didnt make it...

Comment: I've used some of them before. Especially xmodem, but the protocol isnt the issue, its coming up with a RAM friendly way of storing the packets until they are acknowledged and xmodem etc (to my knowledge) dont have any info on that, especially as things like xmodem generally wait for acks/nacks between packets

Comment: Thus the others.  basically it is just validation of the idea of blaze ahead with numbered packets, up to some number of credits (only keeping some max number in flight at any time), if you dont get acks in some amount of time and/or you get nacks you retry.

Comment: It is the wrong kind of protocol.  Only suitable for an unreliable physical layer (bottom of the OSI model), like an RS-232 connection.  The one problem you don't have with Bluetooth.  If you can't get an ACK for a transmitted packet from the recipient then you're stuck.

Comment: I'm designing this for exactly that purpose. The broke. Bluetooth is essentially the bottom of the OSI model as I'm using a Bluetooth bridge in this example, so as far as the master ot slave is concerned, its an issue on the lowest level where bytes just disappear randomly.

Comment: This question is not well suited on stack overflow. It explicitly asks about opinions, which leads to discussions. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use malloc.  Just statically allocate all your packets, perhaps as an array of struct.  But don't use the array to iterate through the packets at run time.  Rather, expand upon your linked-list idea.  Create two lists, one for packets awaiting an ACK and another for free (i.e. available) packets.  At startup, add every packet to the free-list.  When you send a packet, remove it from the free-list and add it to the awaiting-ACK list.  Make the awaiting-ACK list doubly-linked so that you can remove a packet from the middle of the list and return it to the free-list.

If your packet size varies greatly and you want to support more packets with less memory then you can create multiple free-lists for different sized packets.  For example, the max-size-free-list holds the largest packets while the economy-size-free-list holds the smaller packets.  The awaiting-ACK list can hold both sizes as long as it can be known which free-list to return the packets to.  And that can be known by adding a flag to the packet struct.

```
typedef enum PacketSizeType
  PACKET_SIZE_MAX = 0,
  PACKET_SIZE_ECONOMY
} PacketSizeType;

typedef struct PacketBase{
  PacketBase * next;
  PacketBase * prev;
  PacketSizeType type;
  uint8_t data[1];  // a place holder (must be last)
} PacketBase;

typedef struct PacketMax
{
  PacketBase base;  // inherit from PacketBase (must be first)
  uint8_t data[255];
} PacketMax;

typedef struct PacketEconomy
{
  PacketBase base;  // inherit from PacketBase (must be first)
  uint8_t data[30];
} PacketEconomy;

PacketMax MaxSizedPackets[100];
PacketEconomy EconomySizedPackets[100];
Packet *free_list_max;
Packet *free_list_economy;
Packet *awaiting_ack_list;
```

The initialization code should cycle through both arrays, set the `base.type` member to either `MAX` or `ECONOMY`, and add the packet to the appropriate free-list.  The transmit code gets a packet from the appropriately sized free-list and moves it to the awaiting-ACK list.  The awaiting-ACK list can contain both types of packets because they both inherit from the `PacketBase`.  The ACK handler code should check `base.type` to return the packet to the appropriate free-list.

Comment: Thanks kkrambo. Not sure exactly what you mean with free list, but the rest of the idea is nice. do you mean with free list a list of all the possible commands? because that will just get crazy big with the number of commands i have. I can easily distinguish between large and small packets based on the command if i put all the big ones together in the enum so i know that all commands after CMD_BIG or something all go in the large array etc. Thanks for your ideas, much appreciated

Comment: @Ned The free-list is a linked-list that stores the packets that are not currently being used (i.e., the packets that are available).  Removing a packet from the free-list is analogous to malloc.  Returning the packet to the free-list is analogous to freeing it.  The packets are always in either the free-list or the awaiting-ACK list.  Another way to think of it is that the free-list is a pool of empty packets waiting to be used.

Comment: @Ned Storing the un-used packets in the free-list eliminates the need to erase packets after they are used and to iterate through the array to find an empty packet.  Instead you just pull the next packet off the free-list and overwrite whatever junk was in there previously.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense. I like that idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few notes.

- You need to consider ordering. Is it acceptable to have out-of-order delivery?
- Do you care about duplicate packets?
- Lost ACKs have to be detected with a timeout.

My guess is that you care about packet delivery order and you don't want duplicate packets.

A basic approach is to send a packet with a sequence number, wait for an ACK within a timeframe. If you get the ACK, send the next packet in sequence. If you don't get an ACK (consider a timeout and NAK equivalent) then retransmit. Repeat.

The data structure issues then become about queueing in your application while there's an outstanding packet.

If you want to get into multiple outstanding packets you need a more complex data structure and a way of doing selective ACKs. There's a lot of literature out there, but a good place to start is "Computer Networks" by Tannenbaum.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not bothered about out of order packets or duplicates. It would be nice if that didnt happen of course, but what i really need is high throughput of data, and dealing with out of order packets is not a big deal at all. I have sequence numbers, mainly to identify when a packet is missing, not to keep order as such. That book looks like an interesting read and will have a look at that for sure. Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question.